# Jquery select the elements until class `B` or class `A` depending upon which one is found first

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know that I can use `nextUntil()` to select all the elements from a specific element onwards until a specific element is found. For example

```
// select all the elements between class A and class B
$('.A').nextUntil('.B');
```

Now consider that I want to select all the elments from the element having class `A` onwards until an element having class `B` is found, but I want this search to be stopped if there exists another element having class `A` is found. For Example, let's say I have the following structure of elements (classes)

```
A
C
D
E
A  <-- Stop the search and return all the elements till here.
B
```

As you can see, I want the search to be stopped at next `A` if it was found before `B` but when this `A` isn't found, find the next elements until `B` i.e.

```
A
C
D
E
B  <-- Stop the search and return all the elements till here.
C
A
D
E
```

I have been trying to achieve this but I am unable to do so. Is there any way that I can achieve this priority wise selection using jquery `nextUntil()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a simple multiple selector syntax

```
$('.A').nextUntil('.B, .A');
```

Comment: What will it do? Prioritize B over A?

Comment: @KamranAhmed there is no priority assigned, it will take the first element matching either `.a` or `.b`